# How to print out groups of phones with the same manufacturer?

Tags: c

I have learned C Programming Language for about 2 months. I had a homework 3 days ago and I had a problem. Here is the detail of this homework:

Write a program to create an array of phone lists, with the following information: Manufacturer, Warranty period.

- Write a function to input a series of phones with the above information.
- Print out in groups of phones with the same manufacturer.

The input function was easy but the second function was a little bit hard.

for example about how to presentation the second function:

```
phone 1: Sony
phone 2: Samsung
phone 3: Samsung
```

Then you can print it out as

```
Sony: phone 1
Samsung: phone 2, phone 3
```

Depending on your presentation, a clear presentation is okay.

(Sorry about my bad English!!)

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int BH;
    char Name[50];

} DT;

void Import_1Phone(DT& dt)
{
    printf("warranty period: ");
    scanf("%d", &dt.BH);
    rewind(stdin);
    printf("manufacturer name: ");
    gets_s(dt.Name);
}

void Import_List(DT dt[], int& n)
{
    printf("Numbet of phone: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Phone %d : \n", i + 1);
        Import_1Phone(dt[i]);
    }
}


void Export_1Phone(DT dt)
{
    printf("%d\t\t%s\n", dt.BH, dt.Name);
}

void Export_List(DT dt[], int n)
{
    printf("Warranty period\tManufacturer name\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Export_1Phone(dt[i]);
    }
    _getch();
}

void Print_Out(DT dt[], int& n) {
    printf("\nList of phones from the same manufacturer!!!!!!\n");
    DT tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (strcmp(dt[i].Name, dt[j].Name) > 0)
            {
                //please help me!!!! what should I do ?
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    DT dt[100];

    Import_List(dt, n);
    printf("Information of all phone!!");
    Export_List(dt, n);
    Print_Out(dt, n);
    printf("Groups of phones with the same manufacturer");
    .....
    .....
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Simple steps: 1. Get list of all unique manufacturers 2. For each unique manufacturer, find all phones which have this manufacturer name.

Comment: OT: Are you aware that you are writing C++ code? `void function(DT dt[], int& n)` should be `void function(DT dt[], int *n)`, then dereference inside the function with `*n`

Comment: Can I have the example code pls

Comment: Oh sorry now i'm using the .cpp file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.